# How do I properly overload new?

Tags: c++

My code is below. However before `main()` is run something simple such as a `static std::string globalvar;` will call new. Before `MyPool mypool` is initialized.

```
MyPool mypool;
void* operator new(size_t s) { return mypool.donew(s); }
```

Is there anyway I can force mypool to be initialized first? I have no idea how overloading new is suppose to work if there is no way to initialize its values so I am sure there is a solution to this.

I am using both visual studios 2010 and gcc (cross platform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `mypool` a static variable of your `operator new` function:

```
void* operator new(size_t s) {
   static MyPool mypool;
   return mypool.donew(s);
}
```

It will be initialized upon first call of the function (i.e. the operator `new`).

**EDIT**: As the commenters pointed out, declaring the variable as `static` in the `operator new` functions limits its scope and makes it inaccessible in the `operator delete`. To fix that, you should make an accessor function for your pool object:

```
MyPool& GetMyPool() {
  static MyPool mypool;
  return mypool;
}
```

and invoke it in both `operator new` and `operator delete`:

```
void* operator new(size_t s) {
    return GetMyPool().donew(s);
}
// similarly for delete
```

As before, declaring it as static local variable guarantees initialization upon first invocation of `GetMyPool` function. Additionally, it will be the same pool object in both operators which likely what you want.

Comment: That won't work, since he'll doubtlessly have to access the same pool in `operator delete`.

Comment: @James: Could be circumvented by setting a global pointer when first calling the function (i.e., in the constructor of `MyPool`), but it isn't really any better.

Comment: @james. Thats exactly what i did. I made MyPool a global ptr (i should make it a static variable inside of MyPool) which i set to `this`. Although this means i can only have one and it needs to be thread safe.

Comment: I am surprised at how easy this is! thanks! (i'll accept soon)

Comment: @acid: I advise you to still look at my and @James' advices, even if this does work out for you.

Comment: @Xeo: I did. He hasnt yet mentioned where i can find more info on `zero initialization` (i tried a quick search in the standards. That phrase doesnt come up) and he makes no mention that static vars in func are initialized before global static vars -edit- nm i see it in 3.6.2 of the 2003 standards

Comment: @ago See §8.5/5 (in C++03), and §3.6.2 for the order, and §6.7/4 for the
initialization of local static variables.  The important
thing here is that purely static initialization (not to be confused with
the initialization of objects with static lifetime, which can be either
static or dynamic) occurs before any C++ code is run.  So you know that
your pointer will be null before `operator new` can possibly be called.

Answer (score 2):

Properly? Best don't. Try [Boost.Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html), and just use their allocation mechanics. Or if you insist on using your pool, make a new allocation function. I've seen horrible things done to the `operator new`, and I'm feeling sorry for it. :(

IMHO, the only time you should overload `new` is when implementing a memory manager for observation of the allocs / deallocs. Otherwise, just write your own functions and use them instead. Or for most containers, you can give them allocators.

Comment: Overloading the global `operator new` and `operator delete` is tricky; if nothing else, it means that you can't overload it later for memory checking.  It should never be done except at the application level.  But if you want to provide some sort of global placement new (e.g. for specifying the desired pool), you also have to replace the non-placement form, since you have to overload the global `operator delete`, and thus the global `operator new`.

Answer (score 2):

Global initialization occurs in three steps, zero initialization, static
initialization and dynamic initialization.  In that order.  If your
`operator new` uses non-local variables, these variables must depend on
only zero or static initialization; as you said, you cannot guarantee
that your `operator new` won't be called before any particular variable
with dynamic initialization will have occured.

If you need objects with dynamic initialization (often the case), there
are two ways of handling this:

- declare a pointer to the object, rather than the object itself, and
  in `operator new`, check if the pointer is null, and initialize it
  there, or
- call a function which returns a reference to a local instance.

Neither of these solutions is thread safe, but that's likely not a
problem.  They *are* thread safe once the first call returns, so if
there is any invocation of `new` before threading starts, you're OK.
(It's something to keep in mind, however.  If unsure, you can always
allocate and delete an object manually before the first thread is
started—perhaps in the initialization of a static object.)

Comment: How do you "allocate and delete an object manually before the first thread is started" and where can i find more information on "zero initialization" can you give me an example of something that is zero initialize?