# initalizer problem with plugins. a test

Tags: c++, initialization

I had a longer more complicated question and have this code http://www.ideone.com/VEOvp

However i'll simplify it. Is there anything wrong with the code below and is there a better way to do the below?

I am worried about this line `std::list<Plugin*>& plugins` and how to set it while keeping it a reference. But i'll let you guys pick the code apart.

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
class Plugin{
public:
    static std::list<Plugin*>*plugins;
    std::string name;
    Plugin(const std::string&n) : name(n)
    {
      static std::list<Plugin*> plugins;
      this->plugins=&plugins;
      plugins.push_back(this);
    }
};

//main.cpp
#include "plugin.h"

class Plugin1 : public Plugin{
public:
    Plugin1():Plugin("1"){}
};

static Plugin1 plugin;


std::list<Plugin*>* Plugin::plugins;
std::list<Plugin*>& plugins = *Plugin::plugins; //global name plz
int main(){
    for(auto c=plugins.cbegin(); c!=plugins.cend(); ++c) {
        printf("%s\n", (*c)->name.c_str());
    }
}

//PluginA.cpp
#include "plugin.h"

class PluginA : public Plugin{
public:
    PluginA():Plugin("A"){}
};

static PluginA plugin;
```

Comment: I don't get, why you use the static variable of the function to be the destination of the static member pointer. Why don't you declare the member plugins as static std::list<Plugin*> plugins; and work as usual?

Comment: @Nobody: I learned the lesson when i had to overload new http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229046/how-do-i-properly-overload-new/6229077#6229077 the reason is all variables are initialized without order. However if you call a function with a static variable it is guaranteed to be initialized which the reason why i did it. Otherwise i'd have to just hope the static member variable is initialized before the plugin or find another way to guarantee it.

Comment: @acidzombie24: That doesn't work if the "function" you're calling is a construct which is *also* being called statically (as the constructor of a static variable). All static initialization happens first, but the _order_ of static initialization is unknown just as for non-static global initialization.

Comment: This belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: So you need the global name plugins for convenience if I understand you right? If so then you could declare std::list<Plugin*> plugins; globally and use the reference as the static member or don't define it globally and using namespace Plugin; will help you. But I dont like both ways.

Comment: @Nobody: Right. But the problem was Plugin auto registers itself (kind of bad and usual but it is convenient and wont cause compile errors if i remove self registration). The issue was the constructor of plugins may try to register the plugin by adding it to plugins before `list<Plugin*> plugins` was constructed (causing a crash/assert).

Comment: If thats the only problem, why didn't you call the initialization at first in the constructor? That won't be that much overhead as you won't register a zillion plugins and it guarantees to have an initialized list.

Comment: @Nobody: What do you mean? call the static var ctor in Plugin? i never heard of forcing or choosing order of static initalizers/ctors

Comment: It is not the nicest solution but every Plugin constructor could call Plugin::Plugin() to make sure the pluginlist is initialized.

Comment: @Nobody: The problem is, what is it constructing? I guess when it registers itself the add can check if the list is a ptr and if its null since 0 is initialized before anything.

Answer (score 1):

That looks weird to me.
If you goal is to have some sort of global Plugin Container/Manager is there any reason not to use a singleton pattern like this:

```
class PluginContainer {
    static PluginContainer& instance() 
    { 
        static PluginContainer* m_this = 0;
        if(!m_this) 
             m_this = new PluginContainer;
        return *m_this;
    }

    void register(Plugin* plugin) { ... add to a list ... }
    const list<Plugin*>& plugins() const { ... return it ... }

    protected:
        PluginContainer() {}
};

class Plugin{
    public:
    Plugin(const std::string& n) : name(n)
    {
         PluginContainer::instance().register( this );
    }
    private:
    std::string name;
};
```

Comment: I'm not liking the solution. This is worse then my code. The only real problem with my code is i cant access `plugins` with a global scope which this doesnt solve. You might as well say to use plugin::plugins() everytime for safety. You made this even worse by using singletons

Comment: maybe there is some reasoning behind your code i just dont get, but how does `list<Plugin*>& plugins = PluginContainer::instance.plugins()` not solve your problem? Dont get me wrong, I just want to understand why you have to do it in that way. It just looks overly complicated for just getting a global list of plugins.

Comment: +1. I guess it could. Since your forcing the initialization on that line. I know i am only using one instance but i rather not use a singleton since it forces only one instance. If i ever change it, it would break every line that uses `::instance()`

Answer (score 0):

I modified 2 lines and added ForceInit. It should be safe but unconfirmed.

```
Plugin(const std::string&n) : name(n){ static std::list<Plugin*> plugins; this->plugins=&plugins; if(n.length()==0) return; plugins.push_back(this); }
static std::list<Plugin*>* ForceInit() { Plugin d(""); return plugins; }

std::list<Plugin*>& plugins = *Plugin::ForceInit(); //global name plz
```